# Google Chrome Extension Websocket Object error undefined for facebook.com

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am having issue when I use WebSocket object in contentscript.js file of Google Chrome Extension. It produces error only for facebook.com main page. Err.Message gives me undefined value. I am not getting any clue why it is giving error only on facebook.com. Error is produced on the following line

```
var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:3345/");
```

Here is the code snippet of `contentscript.js` :

```
/////////////////////SendMessage/////////////////////// <br/>
//Description: We are creating websocket(Chrome API).  <br/>
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////// <br/>

function SendMessage(message) {
    try {
        if ("WebSocket" in window) {

            //creating websocket(Chrome API)
            //Below code line produces error on facebook.com
            var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:3345/");

            //Hook function against  ws.onmessage event.
            ws.onmessage = function (evt) {

                OnMessage(evt);
            };

            ws.onopen = function () {
              ws.send( message););
            };

        }
    }
    catch (err) { alert("Err->" + err.Message); }
}
```

Here is the mainfest.json code

```
{
  "name" : "myextension",
  "version" : "1.1",
  "description" : "me extension detail",
  "background" : {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },

  "content_scripts" : [
    {
      "matches" : [
        "http://*/*",
        "https://*/*"
      ],
      "js" : ["contentscript.js"],
      "run_at" : "document_end",
      "all_frames" : true
    }
  ],
"permissions": [
    "tabs", "<all_urls>",
 "*://*.facebook.com/",
 "*://www.facebook.com/"

  ],

"content_security_policy": "script-src https://www.facebook.com 'self'; object-src 'self'; connect-src https://www.facebook.com",

  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

Comment: How was this websocket server created?

Comment: Where does the code reside in your extension? Did you specify sufficient permissions in manifest?

Comment: If you change `localhost` to a real IP does this help? Also make sure the page you're connecting from at facebook is not served by some cdn domain other than `facebook.com`. Can you place `*://*/*` in permissions?

Comment: After doing the recommended changes I am still on same issue. No progress.

Comment: I have moved WebSocket creation code in background.js file. Now I am having undefinded error on every website download event. Is it correct to move websocket code from contentscript.js to background.js?